# Unit test: running programmatically a code that runs only at a real application instance

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin for PhpStorm, and in some point, it try to [`getContainingClass()`](https://github.com/rentalhost/laravel-insight/blob/890c3a23e41da3a33ef0be85aef322000dc82d1e/src/laravelInsight/annotation/ColumnWithoutAnnotationInspection.java#L90) from visited `method`. This method should return `null` when the class name is absent.

Just to make easier to explain, my `visitPhpMethod()` is like that:

```
final PhpClass methodClass = method.getContainingClass();

if (methodClass == null) {
    return null;
}
```

My problem is justly to make the code-coverage of `return null` programmatically (*from unit test*) to proof that it is not a *dead code*. From a real instance of PhpStorm running my plugin I can reach this code when I just remove the class name like that:

**Original code, that not access the `return null`:**

```
class ThisIsMyClass { function x(){} }
```

**Modified code without the class name, that access `return null`:**

```
class               { function x(){} }
```

But when I run the modified code from unit test, it give that:

```
class<error descr="Expected: class name"> </error>{ function x(){} }
```

And with that, my `visitPhpMethod()` is not triggered (*while in real PhpStorm application it does*). In this way, is impossible to coverage this part of code (**but I like to do**).

---

**My best attempt:** instead I relying on `testHighlight()` for that, I inputted with the functional code (that have the class name), then programatically I removed the class name (then the "expected class name" error don't happen anymore). Finally I run the `visitPhpMethod()` programmatically.

Unfortunatelly, the `getContainingClass()` instead of return `null` (that is what I expect to do), it just returns a `PhpClass` instance that don't have a name (and it should not works to me).

The code from this attempt could be [seen here](https://pastebin.com/5HC4pBj5).

I tried to post the [same problem](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000343550-Unit-test-checking-for-a-NPE-where-exists-an-error-before?page=1) on Intellij Community too, but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found my issue.

On reality, the problem is not on `getContaingClass()`. It really doesn't returns `null` when called from `visitPhpMethod()`. I found my problem on another method that try to `getNameIdentifier()` from the containing class, in this case, it is really absent and I just try to return it from a `@NotNull` method.